# Rails: Generate QR Code in Prawn PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, qr-code, prawn

I'm trying to generate a pdf document with different QRcodes and am using the following gems

```
gem 'prawn'
gem 'prawn-qrcode'
```

Issue is, I can't seem to print out the QRcode with the following method:

```
require 'prawn/qrcode'

class QrcodePdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize (deal)
    super()
    @deal = deal
    title
    @deal.venues.each do |venue|
      text "QR Code for: #{venue.name}"
      qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new(@deal.id.to_s + "_" + venue.id.to_s + "_" + @deal.created_at.to_s)
      render_qr_code(qrcode)
    end
  end

  def title
    text "Title of deal: #{@deal.title}", size: 16, style: :bold
  end
end
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

**Edit: Additional Info**

Sorry, i forgot to state that the pdf is actually being compiled. But the QRCode section is blank.
So it just print the text of QR Code for ... in the loop.

Also, I've printed out the string in @deal.id.to_s ... and it does contain the data I want, so I'm not sure what went wrong.

I've also refereed to https://github.com/jabbrwcky/prawn-qrcode in the usage section.

Comment: You should add what error you are getting. Posting code that says 'this doesnt work' is not helpful for us trying to help you.

Comment: Hi @Deekor, Sorry i made the necessary changes in the question

Comment: How can you put the QR code in a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably bug with `prawn-qrcode`, but `render_qr_code` is not working. At least for `Ruby 2.2.3` (I didn't tested if for older versions).

Still you can use `print_qr_code` method and it's functional:

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => "A4") do
  print_qr_code("some-text", extent: 96, stroke: false)
end
```

Comment: Ah I see. No wonder it doesn't work. Your solution works perfectly! Thanks for the help, much appreciated!